# Thai line breaks on iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, localization, thai

I'm working on Thai localization for the mobile game in Unity. The problem occurs when I send Thai text via push notifications, as the system does not break lines properly. It breaks only by spaces, but fails to recognize actual words. I assume there is a problem with the text I pass to the notification, since there is a native support for the language in these systems and they manage to break lines somehow (cannot say for sure though, because I don't know Thai).

The question is: how do iOS and Android recognise where to insert a line break in the Thai text? Are there any special hidden symbols or some other techniques involved? Can I even make my custom text be properly handled by the system?

**UPDATE:** To clarify the issue: in Thai language they do not separate words with spaces. Spaces are ment to act like periods in English. Therefore, it is possible that a sentense may be just a sigle long line of text without any separators. And when such a line exceeds the boundaries of push notification it gets broken in the middle of the word, not between two words. For example

```
ให้แตะปุ่มเมนูที่ด้านซ้ายบนของหน้าจอตัวละครหลัก
```

gets broken into

```
ให้แตะปุ่มเมนูที่ด้านซ้ายบนของ
หน้าจอตัวละครหลัก
```

Even though correctly in would be

```
ให้แตะปุ่มเมนูที่ด้านซ้ายบน
ของหน้าจอตัวละครหลัก
```

So I cannot just insert \n between every two words, it may be done only in the paces of line wraps

Comment: @iMHiteshSurani, could you please explain in a bit more detail? I don't quite get the idea.

Comment: I mean to say use \n for line break

Comment: Updated the issue to make it more clear

Comment: Unfortunately, There is no hope because the content wrapping for notification is done OS itself based on text length, Spaces between text and device you are using. I am deleting my answer, I think it is not useful for you. But I would like to suggest use space after some specific character, It is only one hope to resolve your issue. Thanks